# How can I use DirectX to create a video editor in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, directx

Is it possible to create a video editor in C# by using DirectX or should I use a different SDK to make a video editor? Keep in mind that I need to be able to animate objects (shapes and paths like in After Effects if possible).

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Drop Seriously?! He's just asking if it's the right technology to learn and invest in, not how to do it. *PS*: I think he tried this: `for(unsigned int it = 1; it >= 0; --it);` but it didn't work, took too long.

Comment: If you're asking this question, I don't think you're yet up to the task of creating a video editor and you're slightly underestimating the task... Not to mention that you usually use C++ for such a tool as it needs to be as fast as possible, memory efficient and more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are really two Windows APIs you should consider for a video editor:

- **Media Foundation** which is the modern Windows media API for video and audio.
- **DirectShow** which is an older technology that dates back to the late 90s.

The *DirectX SDK* is not applicable to video application development. DirectShow was pulled out of the DirectX SDK back in April 2005. Media Foundation never shipped in the DirectX SDK. See [DirectX SDKs of a certain age](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/08/22/directx-sdk-s-of-a-certain-age.aspx).

> Note that even the DirectX SDK itself is legacy these days. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx)

Instead, these APIs are available in the Windows SDK. If you are using Visual Studio, you likely already have a copy of this SDK. For a list of versions, see [A Brief History of Windows SDKs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/10/03/a-brief-history-of-windows-sdks.aspx)

To make use of either of these APIs from C#, you should take a look at [Media Foundation](http://mfnet.sourceforge.net/) and [directshow.net](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/).

> There is a Direct3D 11 Video technology that is part of the DirectX 11.1 Runtime (Windows 8 SDK or later). It is extremely low-level and is really intended for things like Media Foundation itself to use as a renderer with some ability to do GPU acceleration of the processing.